# Does filter() throw an exception?

Tags: django, django-models

Does `filter()` throw an exception if there are no selected objects present in the database like `get()` or does it return `None`?

I am having this code here:

```
# Return a list of all chat posts attached to that chat_instance, if it exists.
chat_posts_list = models.ChatPost.objects.filter(chat_instance=chat_instance)
```

A `ChatInstance` can have zero or many `ChatPost`s, implying that for some certain cases, a specific `ChatInstance` may turn out to have no `ChatPosts`, so `filter()` will not return a full list. What will happen in that situation? Will `filter()` return `None`, or will it throw an exception? How should I handle that?

Comment: no it doesn't throw... it just return an empty queryset... also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter will return an empty queryset. You could handle it by doing something like:

```
if not chat_posts_list:
    #dosomething
else:
    #do something else
```